# Only want one function to be imported yet the full program comes over

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I made 2 programs for show porpose. I would like to import the global variable from the transmitter function into another file, yet the problem that I encounter is that the While true loop also comes along spoiling my whole second program, because the second problem now also starts to show the itiration.

Program 1:

```
import time

def transmitter():
    global temp

global temp
temp = 2

transmitter()

while True: # a random task just to see if I only imported the function
    x = 0
    print(x + 1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Program 2:

```
from transmitguy import transmitter

def valuepullup():
    newval = transmitguy.transmitter()
    print(newval)

valuepullup()
```

I only need my second program to show the value of 2 once. (2 is the globalvar from file 1)

Comment: Put everything but the function into [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/1639625)

Comment: Where is `OpenUSB` defined?

Comment: fixed the file, the original program was called openUSB, changed the name for upload

Comment: put it in the [if __name__ == "__main__":], it now gives the value none

Comment: Your function returns `None`, since you haven't written it to return anything else. It's a useless function, since it doesn't do anything at all. I'm not sure what you expect your `global` statements to do, but currently they're completely pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't get only one piece of a module.  `from x import y` imports `x` in the same way `import x` does.  The only difference is that, in the former case, `y` is added to your current global namespace, and in the latter case, `x` is.  The [docs for `import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) say:

> The `from` form ... find[s] the module specified in the `from` clause, loading and initializing it if necessary ...

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  As the commenters noted, you can check for `__main__`.  However, you might do better to put your variable in its own module, then import that module from both of your existing modules.

See also [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).